# Testing a Meteor JS API endpoint

Tags: unit-testing, testing, meteor, iron-router

I've recently created a small application using Meteor JS. The application handles user input via a series of forms and stores the data in MongoDB.

One of the requirements for this projects was to developer an API with around 8 end-points.

When requested, an end-point returns a JSON object.

The API end-points/routes have been created using Iron Router.

My question is; how would one go about testing these end-points in Meteor JS. Ideally I'd like to mock the requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools. Below are my suggestions.

For `GET`, I usually just type it in the browser's URL bar.

For `POST` or all other including `GET`, I use `cURL` from the command line like so:

```
curl -X POST \
https://saturnapi.com/access/demo/demo \
-H 'saturnapi-access-key':'API_KEY' \
-d 'SaturnParams'='28' \
```

`-H` specifices the headers, which in this case is my API key. `-d` specifies the data, which in this case is `SaturnParams` field. For more on `cURL`, see docs [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).